# Interacting with physical pin GPIO

Tags: python, java, android

Is there any permission to write in the android manifest to be able to interact with a physical GPIO pin? I can already give the voltage to the gpio pin through the android application. But, I still can't interact with the GPIO pin to give an input?
How should I do it?

As requested, this are my python code to use in the android environment:

```
import OPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

def gpio_control_on():
    # Set up GPIO mode
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    # Set pins 12, 16, and 18 as outputs
    GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

    # Perform GPIO control for ON state
    GPIO.output(10, GPIO.HIGH)

    # Delay for a certain amount of time (optional, if you want to see the effect)
    time.sleep(1)

    # Clean up GPIO
    GPIO.cleanup()

def gpio_control_off():
    # Set up GPIO mode
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    # Set pins 10, 16, and 18 as outputs
    GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

    # Perform GPIO control for OFF state
    GPIO.output(10, GPIO.LOW)

    # Delay for a certain amount of time (optional, if you want to see the effect)
    time.sleep(1)

    # Clean up GPIO
    GPIO.cleanup()

def gpio_control():
    # Set up GPIO mode
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    # Set pin 7 as an input
    GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN)

    # Read the value of pin 7
    pin7_value = GPIO.input(7)

    # Check the state of pin 7
    if pin7_value == GPIO.HIGH:
        # Call the gpio_control_on() function
        gpio_control_on()
    else:
        # Call the gpio_control_off() function
        gpio_control_off()

    # Delay for a certain amount of time
    # (optional, if you want to see the effect)
    time.sleep(1)

    # Clean up GPIO
    GPIO.cleanup()

# Call gpio_control() function
gpio_control()
```

then I called the function in the Main Activity in onCreate section:

```
  ToggleButton toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            boolean isChecked = toggleButton.isChecked();
            // Call the appropriate Python function based on the ToggleButton state
            if (isChecked) {
                callGpioControlFunction("gpio_control_on");
            } else {
                callGpioControlFunction("gpio_control_off");
            }

        });
```

and in the xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="245dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="@string/ID_Tag"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.554"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.243" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/History_ID"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.543"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.475" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:textOn="@string/toggle_on"
        android:textOff="@string/toggle_off"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.109"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.811" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Whenever I press the toggle button, the android application will crash immideatly. why?

Comment: Where on my device are those pins?

Comment: I am using micro c board running android os. In controlling the GPIO, I have built a python program. If the program does not interact with android layout directly, the condition can be achieved. but, when the program is built to interact with gpio through the android layout, the app crashes. why?

Comment: Post the relevant logcat lines.

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: have found out the reason of crashing. thank you